# Android Studio Issue after running the app

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-studio

So i have created an android application with the help of xml and kotlin , the name of my Application is "Data_Application" so after completing the coding part when i run the app it showed me an error like
(Data Applications has stpped) and showing me some options like 1)App info 2)close app i have checked my code multiple times on  multiple devices and in Chat gpt too but still this error is coming Can anybody please help me?

This is the error its showing [Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZ9h7.jpg)

Comment: Your app crashed, check the Logcat for exception log

Comment: Mention the log here so that we can help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.